# Different ways of setting CXX standard

Tags: cmake

Whenever it comes to set C++ standard in a project I generally use this way:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED On)
```

But recently I came across a recommendation where they suggest to use this way:

```
set_property(TARGET MyApp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED On)
```

Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: In the second snippet instead of `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED On)` you probably mean `set_property(TARGET MyApp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`. Otherwise, the variable's setting doesn't affect on the `MyApp` target which has been defined before.

Comment: Strange because I've got this from a book called "Modern CMake for C++" by Rafal Swidzinski and he got these things in the order I've described. But what is more interesting is that in his github repo examples he is actually using the first approach I've mentioned.

Comment: A bit more recent and concise style wrt targets is `target_compile_features(my_target PRIVATE cxx_std_17)`.

Comment: Why after reading the book do you ask about difference between `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` and `set_property(TARGET MyApp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)`? The book describes that difference: variable `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` specifies a "**default** value for all subsequently defined targets", and using property CXX_STANDARD "you can overwrite it on a **per-target** basis, if needed".

Comment: Alright, going back and read it again it seems that I misunderstood the authors message. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You may want to use `target_compile_features(MyApp PRIVATE cxx_std_17)` since this simply states a minimum and allows for "inheritance" (on libs) in case you're using new C++ language features in your public headers and still gives the user the freedom of choosing a higher C++ standard during configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rereading the recommendation I realized that I misunderstood the message. The thing is that we use this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED On)
```

To set a **default** standard for all targets. But with some targets we might want to user a different standard (a newer one for example) and then we can override it for this specific target as such:

```
set_property(TARGET FooLib PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

Thanks to @Tsyvarev for pointing this out.